# Wcf exception handling throw an error

Tags: wcf, exception, faultexception

Hi I have a problem handling exceptions in wcf.
I have a service like this one:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAddressService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ExecuteCommandException))]
    int SavePerson(string idApp, int idUser, Person person);
}
```

I am calling the SavePerson() on the service in the WCFTestClient utility.
The SavePerson() implementation is:

```
public int SavePerson(string idApp, int idUser, Person person)
{
    try
    {
        this._savePersonCommand.Person = person;

        this.ExecuteCommand(idUser, idApp, this._savePersonCommand);

        return this._savePersonCommand.Person.Id;
    }
    catch (ExecuteCommandException ex)
    {
        throw new FaultException<ExecuteCommandException>(ex, new FaultReason("Error in   'SavePerson'"));
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible
>   causes: The service is offline or
>   inaccessible; the client-side
>   configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid.
>   Refer to the stack trace for more
>   detail. You can try to recover by
>   starting a new proxy, restoring to
>   default configuration, or refreshing
>   the service.

if I change the SavePerson method and instead of:

```
catch (ExecuteCommandException ex)
{
    throw new FaultException<ExecuteCommandException>(ex, new FaultReason("Error in   'SavePerson'"));
}
```

I do

```
catch(Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

I don't get the above error, but I only get the exception message and no inner exception.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is ExecuteCommandException serializable?

Comment: ExecuteCommandException  inherits from Exception and is marked serializable. I found that if I send exception the above error happens. And found that when an exception is thrown at the server side, wcf closes the channel and disconnects the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the fault contract:

```
[FaultContract(typeof(ExecuteCommandException))]
```

you must not specify an exception type. Instead, you specify a data contract of your choice to pass back any values that you deem necessary.

For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class ExecuteCommandInfo {
    [DataMember]
    public string Message;
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IAddressService {
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ExecuteCommandInfo))]
    int SavePerson(string idApp, int idUser, Person person);
}

catch (ExecuteCommandException ex) { 
    throw new FaultException<ExecuteCommandInfo>(new ExecuteCommandInfo { Message = ex.Message }, new FaultReason("Error in   'SavePerson'")); 
}
```